# Ruby Syntax: Bitmask

Tags: ruby, syntax

I'm having a lot of difficulty putting together what the [following code](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization) is supposed to do (I understand what it's supposed to do, I just can't put together the pieces):

```
def roles=(roles)
  self.roles_mask = (roles & ROLES).map { |r| 2**ROLES.index(r) }.inject(0, :+)
end

def roles
  ROLES.reject do |r|
    ((roles_mask || 0) & 2**ROLES.index(r)).zero?
  end
end
```

`ROLES` is an array specified in the link. I'm assuming `roles` is also an array.

1. Why have a setter method and a regular method with the same name?
2. What array serves as the object of the `map` method? If `roles` is `['author', 'editor']` and `ROLES` is `['author', 'editor', 'manager']`, how does the `&` operator create an array for `map`?
3. What is `2**ROLES`? *I figured out that this is really just `2` raised to the power of `ROLES.index(r)`.*
4. "[Bitmask attributes on a Rails application](http://asilia.heroku.com/2011/04/06/bitmask-attributes-on-a-rails-application)" says that `(roles & ROLES)` is sanitizing the parameters `roles` against the array `ROLES`, but what does sanitizing it mean?
5. If `r` is the current value of the array `(roles & ROLES)`, how does the `index` method of `2**ROLES` return `r`? *I figured out that this is returning the position of `roles` in the array `ROLES`, but I still don't know how `(roles & ROLES).map` interacts/works with this.*
6. How does the `inject` method work on the condition in the brackets for the `map` method?

I'd like to figure out how this bitmasking works, but I have no idea how what's on the right side of the equation for `def roles=(roles)` returns an integer.

Comment: 1. `roles=` is a different method name than `role`. 2. Array#& : Returns a new array containing elements common to the two arrays, with no duplicates. (explanation found in The Pickaxe http://pragprog.com/book/ruby3/programming-ruby-1-9)

Comment: "roles= is a different method name than role"

But the second one is named "roles." So are you saying roles=() and roles are two different method names? If so, i get that. And thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the typo. We say that `roles` is a _getter_, returns a value, and `roles=()` is a _setter_, modifies the value. Writing `roles    =   xyz` is a syntactic sugar of Ruby. Actually the equal sign is part of the name of the method, if roles is a method. But in `var   =   xyz`, if var is a variable, the equal sign is just the assign operator.  A search with **attr_accessor** will give you plenty of answers, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370960/what-is-attr-accessor-in-ruby

Comment: Ruby's IRB is great for trying these things out for yourself. Create dummy values for `roles` and `ROLES` and see what `(roles & ROLES)` returns. Follow that with the `map` statement and see what happens. 
Stack Overflow greatly prefers a single question. Multiple questions dilute and confuse the possible answers, so try to keep them restricted. One or two questions is manageable. Six is overboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the `index` call converts the given roles to integers by determining their position in the array of `ROLES`. 2 is then raised to the power of this index and `inject` simply sums the the results.

Put simply

Step 1 is to get roles that are found in ROLES by using `&` to se which values in the two arrays match.

Step 2, for each matching role compute 2**index. Map returns an array of these values.

Step 3, sum the array to get the final integer.

The idea is to compute a unique integer for each combination of roles.

The getter simply unwinds the process returning the combination of roles that match.