# How does attr_accessor work in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is attr_accessor in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370960/what-is-attr-accessor-in-ruby)

Here's the sample code:

```
class User
  attr_accessor :name, :email

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    @name = attributes[:name]
    @email = attributes[:email] 
  end 

....

end
```

When I do

```
example = User.new
```

it creates an empty user and I can assign its name and email by

```
example.name = "something"
example.email = "something"
```

My question is, why this thing works? How does the computer know that example.name means the @name variable in the class? I'm assuming name and :name are different, and here in the code we have not explicitly told the computer that example.name is equivalent to :name symbol.

Comment: Oh yeah. Of course, it's answered already :)

Answer (score 5):

What `attr_accessor` does is it creates a couple of methods, a getter and a setter. It uses a symbol you pass to construct names of methods and instance variable. Look, this code:

```
class User
  attr_accessor :name
end
```

is equivalent to this code

```
class User
  def name
    @name
  end

  def name=(val)
    @name = val
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

`attr_accessor :field` is the same as calling `attr_reader :field` and `attr_writer :field`. Those in turn are roughly the equal to:

```
def field
  @field
end

def field=(value)
  @field = value
end
```

Welcome to the magic of meta-programming. ;)