# attr_accessor and attr_reader not working in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to migrate an application to rails 4 and ruby2.

In my model `Product`, I had this :

```
attr_accessor :name, :age, :price
```

which I switched to :

```
attr_reader :name, :age, :price
```

In my view I have this :

```
  %td.small
    = number_with_precision(@p.get_last_usd_price.to_f, precision: 2, delimiter: ",", strip_insignificant_zeros: true)
```

Everything worked fine with rails 3.2 and `attr_accessor`. But now I have an issue in `get_last_usd_price` :

```
  def get_last_usd_price
    price = 0.0
    puts "--------------------"
    puts self.inspect          #---> prints a #<product> with all the correct attributes
    puts
    puts self.name.inspect     #---> prints nil
    puts @name.inspect         #---> prints nil
    puts "--------------------"
    # blah blah
  end
```

Basically, all the variables are nil when I try to access them but they are correctly saved into the object instance.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Edit : The controller

```
  def detail_product
    @p = Product.find(params[:product_id]) if params[:product_id].present?
    if !@p.present? then
      flash[:error] = 'No product id'
      redirect_to  :action => :products
    end
  end
```

Comment: Just for the sake of it, try to remove the attr readers/attr accessors if the attributes :name, :age, and :price are saved in the database

Comment: Another thing to note is that it may be possible that you never filled `@name` in, unless you're expecting Rails to do it automagically from the database.

Comment: @Zippie Your solution works. Why?! Anyway, I need to have something like `attr_reader` for database migrations etc... So what should I use instead of `attr_reader` ?

Comment: yeah, show us your controllers

Comment: no you don't, i believe Rails sets the attr readers and attr writters, so you're all set to go

Comment: @Zippie Thank you for that but do you have any documentation refering to that? :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14452353/1279707

Comment: @Zippie <3 you should create an answer and I'll validate it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remove the `attr_readers`/`attr_accessors` if the attributes `:name`, `:age`, and `:price` are saved in the database, since Rails defines those methods already.

For more check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14452353/1279707