# Class attribute losing value after initialize ends

Tags: ruby, scope, instance-variables

Can someone please help me understand why the class attribute is losing the value outside the initialize method?

```
2.0.0-p0 :031 > $arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
 => [1, 2, 3, 4] 
2.0.0-p0 :032 > class Class1
2.0.0-p0 :033?>   def initialize
2.0.0-p0 :034?>     val1 = $arr[0]
2.0.0-p0 :035?>     puts val1
2.0.0-p0 :036?>     end 
2.0.0-p0 :037?>   end 
=> nil 
2.0.0-p0 :038 > cl1 = Class1.new
1   
=> #<Class1:0x007fe8ac16be70> 
2.0.0-p0 :039 > puts cl1.val1

=> nil 
2.0.0-p0 :040 >
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a lot of programming languages, including Ruby, variables are [scoped](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Ruby_Variable_Scope), and in your code `val1` is in the **local scope**. It is forgotten when the scope – in this case the function – ends. You probably wanted an instance variable.

> A local variable has a name starting with a lower case letter or an underscore character (_).

> Each object represents its own song, so we need each of our Song objects to carry around its own song name, artist, and duration. This means **we need to store these values as instance variables within the object**. In Ruby, an instance variable is simply a name preceded by an `at` sign (`@`).

One you have an instance variable, you can access it.

```
class Person
  def name
    @name # simply returning an instance variable @name
  end
end

person = Person.new
person.name # => nil
```

But you won't be able to **set** a value:

```
person.name = "miku" # => no method error
```

So for read **and** write access you'll need provide writer methods or use [`attr_accessor`](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/accessors.html). This answer explains it in examples: [What is attr_accessor in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4371458/89391)

Refs:

- http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/localvars.html
- http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_classes.html

Comment: I had val1 as a member variable. But was trying to reopen a class and add functionality to it. That was a good catch. I think the issue was because of the missing `@`.

Answer (score 2):

Continuing from @miku's answer you need to define var1 as instance variable to be able to be accessed outside of initialize

```
irb(main):013:0> class Class1
irb(main):014:1>   attr_accessor :val1
irb(main):015:1>   def initialize
irb(main):016:2>     @val1 = $arr[0]
irb(main):017:2>     puts @val1
irb(main):018:2>     end
irb(main):019:1>   end
=> nil
irb(main):020:0> c = Class1.new
1
=> #<Class1:0x8016f79e0 @val1=1>
irb(main):021:0> puts c.val1
1
=> nil
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably what you are trying to do is:

```
class Class1
  def initialize
    @val1 = $arr[0]
    puts @val1
  end 
end
```

Although maybe it would be better to pass the value you want to initialize in the constructor's argument:

```
class Class1
  def initialize(val)
    @val1 = val
    puts @val1
  end 
end

cl1=Class1.new($arr[0])
```