# Ruby/Cucumber Composition design

Tags: ruby, automation, webdriver, cucumber, bdd

A slight problem I'm fairly new to Ruby, I have a class which contains instances of other classes(composition)

I'm trying to access the class instances within Cucumber, but keep returning a error
 **undefined method `bk' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)**
'bk' method is located inside the **interior class**
I'm guessing this error is because Cucumber cannot access the class of Interior. 
Whats the best way of designing this or a suitable solution?

```
class CarConfig


def initialize(browser, wait)
@browser = browser
@wait = wait
@equipments = Equipment.new(@browser)
@interior = Interior.new(@browser)
@engines = Engines.new(@browser)
@exterior = Exterior.new(@browser)
@grades = Grades.new(@browser)
end

def click_comfort
@browser.find_element(:css, 'a.xdata-id-Comfort').click
end


def check_equipment
  equipment_availability = []
  equipment_not_available = " equipment not available"
  equipment_currently_available = "equipment available"

 equipment = [@equipments.lifestyle,@equipments.elegance, @equipments.comfort,   @equipments.executive, @equipments.luxury,
             @equipments.innova].each do

end
  equipment_availability.push equipment

 if "#{equipment_availability}".include? "disabled"
   equipment_not_available
 else
   equipment_currently_available
 end
```

end

```
 Cucumber 

 Given /^I have selected Comfort$/ do
 @car_configurator = CarConfig.new(@browser, @wait)
 @browser.get $car_config_page
 sleep(2)
 @car_configurator.click_comfort
 sleep(3)

 end

 Then /^I should see interior BK as available$/ do
 @interior.bk.should_not include ("disabled"), ("selected")
 end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem Simplified**

The problem can be simplified to be seen without Cucumber (ie the problem is general ruby coding issue):

```
class Interior
    def bk()
        return 'bk method'
    end
end 

class CarConfig
    def initialize(browser, wait)
        @browser = browser
        @wait = wait
        @interior = Interior.new
    end
end

@car_configurator = CarConfig.new('browser', 'wait')
@interior.bk
#=> stuff.rb:16:in `<main>': undefined method `bk' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

The problem is that `@interior` does not exist within the scope of the main (or in your case the cucumber step). It is only defined within the instance of the CarConfig - ie `@car_configurator`.

**Solution**

If you want to access the `@interior`, you need to create a method for this within the CarConfig. It is mostly easily done with an [attribute accessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370960/what-is-attr-accessor-in-ruby). The CarConfig class would have the following line added:

```
attr_accessor :interior
```

So that the class becomes:

```
class CarConfig
    attr_accessor :interior

    def initialize(browser, wait)
        @browser = browser
        @wait = wait
        @interior = Interior.new
    end
end
```

To then call the `bk` method of the `@interior` object, you would then need to access it starting from the `@car_configurator`:

```
@car_configurator.interior.bk
#=> "bk method"
```