# Ruby constructor self vs @

Tags: ruby

I have created folowing simple class:

```
class Test
  def initialize(a, b)
    @a = a
    @b = b
  end

  def test
    puts @a
  end
end
```

IS there a way to replace `@a` with `self`? Everytime I tried to do this I received an error:

```
undefined method `a'
```

The reason I am doing this is because I would like to create a new object with two parameters, and later operate on these parameters like:

```
d = MyObject('title', 'Author')
d.showAuthor
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done and actually [is done](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html) for these classes: Array, String, Integer, Float, Rational, Complex and Hash. If you consider the Test class (bad name by the way) of equal importance then consider:

```
class Test
  def initialize(a, b)
    @a = a
    @b = b
  end

  def test
    puts @a
  end
end

module Kernel
  def Test(*args)
    Test.new(*args)  #that's right, just call new anyway!
  end
end

book = Test('title', 'Author')
book.test # => title
```

Since the `Kernel` module is inherited by `Object`, the global namespace now has a Test method. Don't do this unless you absolutely need it.

Comment: BTW: it's common practice to make such methods that are not actually intended to be *called* as methods (they are more like global procedures) `private` so that you don't accidentally call them like `foo.Test('bla')`.

Answer (score 5):

```
class Test
  attr_accessor :a,:b   #creates methods a,b,a=,b= and @a and @b variables

  def initialize(a, b)
    self.a = a  #calls a=
    self.b = b  #calls b=
  end

  def test
    puts a  #calls method a; self.a would do the same.
  end

  def self.[](a,b)
    new(a,b)
  end
end
```

This will let you drop the new (but you have to change the parens to square brackets)  So you can call:

```
d=Test['dog','cat']
d.a  #'dog'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define accesors, you can do it using `attr_*`:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :a,:b

  def initialize(a, b)
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
  end
end
```

Also do not use `camelCase` in Ruby, there is convention to name:

- variables - `snake_case`
- methods - `snake_case`
- classes - `CapitalCamelCase`
- constants - `CAPITAL_SNAKE_CASE`

Comment: `attr_accessible` is removed from ActiveRecord and was never part of Ruby. You probably meant to say `attr_accessor`.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `self.a`, Ruby is looking for a method `a` for the class represented by `self`, so you get an undefined method error (since you did not define a method called `a`). You probably are looking for:

```
class Test
  attr_accessor :a, :b

  def initialize(a, b)
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
  end

  def test
    puts self.a   # "puts a" would be adequate here since it's not ambiguous
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes this is what I have. But is there a way of not using .new?

Comment: @user665967 No ruby doesn't let you overload the `()`'s. But you can overload `[]` to get `Test[ "foo", "bar" ]`. This isn't Python, don't try to beat the syntax int it

Comment: @steenslag oops and thanks! Duh, talk about a brain fart...

Answer (score 1):

So you need to access your instance variables from outside the instance? You can use attr_accessor to do that:

```
class Test
  attr_accessor :a
  attr_accessor :b

  def initialize(a, b)
    @a = a
    @b = b
  end
end

t = Test.new(:foo, :bar)
t.a
t.b
```

`attr_accessor` let's you both read and write the instance variable. If you only need to read it, you can use `attr_reader`, and if you only need to change it you can use `attr_writer`.

More on attribute accessors: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4371458/289219

Comment: what's the difference between attr_ and attribute_ ?

Comment: There is no such thing called `attribute_accessor` in plain ruby.

Comment: @user665967 the difference is in one case I screwed up (`attribute_`) and the other case is correct (`attr_`)

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyClass

  def initialize(title,author)
    @title = title
    @author = author
  end

  def showAuthor
    @author
  end

end
```

That will produce...

```
d = MyClass.new("Grapes of Wrath", "Steinbeck")
d.showAuthor
=> "Steinbeck"
```

Comment: Yes this is what I have. But is there a way of not using .new? and using self instead of @ ?