# Instance variables and setter method - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to update two attributes in a method like this:

```
def my_method
  @from = @to = Time.zone.now
end
```

but when I call this method I don't get set values in from and to:

```
my_model.from => nil
my_model.to   => nil
```

with this it works:

```
self.from = self.to = Time.zone.now

my_model.from => Sat, 20 Jul 2013 20:54:40 UTC 00:00
```

1. do you know why the first way does not work?
2. could you give me some advice about the difference between these? how are they called? instance vars or attr_accessors? actually I need help defining this second question.

## Update

`from` and `to` are persisted attributes

Comment: Do you use `attr_accessor` for `from` and `to` in your class ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370960/what-is-attr-accessor-in-ruby

Comment: If they're *persisted* properties  you *must* use self: persisted properties are *not* simple attributes. But you don't say what they are.

Comment: did you mean me? `from` and `to` are persisted attributes

Comment: @juanpastas see Dave's answer, he is right.

Answer (score 1):

Persisted attributes are *not* simple attributes/instance variables.

They are managed by ActiveRecord and you must use the `self.xxx` when setting them.

When *reading* them, e.g., `obj.from`, it's calling the accessor added by active record.

Comment: When I use `obj.from` with `attr_accessor` there is an instance variable `@from` in `obj`, right? so in this case ActiveRecord accessor does not define such instance variable, right? any link to read how this works?

Comment: @juanpastas Correct; `attr_accessor` creates getter and setter methods. Persisted AR properties use DB properties to create those same methods, and they don't use instance variables, IIRC it's a hash but I'd have to look it up. I don't recall the best reference for all this at the moment, I'm sorry.

Answer (score -1):

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :from, :to

  def my_method
    @from = @to = Time.now
  end
end

foo = Foo.new()
foo.my_method
puts foo.from  # => 2013-07-20 17:06:51 -0400
puts foo.to    # => 2013-07-20 17:06:51 -0400
```

Comment: will this present conflict with from to which are persisted attributes, any link to read how this works?

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel In fairness, it was not originally clear from the OP's post what precisely they were doing, hence my clarifying comment.