# Create an new instance of class in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm a beginner at programming and wrote a simple program:

```
class Chapter
  def initialize
@text
@number
  end
end

def new_chapter
  tmp_chapter = Chapter.new
  tmp_chapter.text = 'Chapter about ..'
  tmp_chapter.number = '11'
end

puts new_chapter
puts ObjectSpace.each_object(Chapter) {|x| p x}
```

But I get this error:

```
 test2.rb:10:in `new_chapter': undefined method `text=' for #<Chapter:0x200b830>
 (NoMethodError)
 from test2.rb:14:in `<main>'
```

So what did I do wrong? I know there are other ways to create a new instance but I want to do it this way! Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to this :

```
class Chapter
 attr_accessor :text, :number
 def initialize
  @text
  @number
 end
end
```

You could write this as below,no need of `def initialize ;@text; @number; end`.

```
class Chapter
 attr_accessor :text,:number
end
def new_chapter
 tmp_chapter = Chapter.new
 tmp_chapter.text = 'Chapter about ..'
 tmp_chapter.number = '11'
end

puts new_chapter
puts ObjectSpace.each_object(Chapter) {|x| p x}
# >> 11
# >> #<Chapter:0x9596eac @text="Chapter about ..", @number="11">
# >> 1
```

Comment: also note the initialiser does nothing at the moment

Comment: @JanDvorak I can't edit the line you mentioned.. There is some lock in the post. :(

Comment: You've got a typo on the second line of your first code example. `attr_accessor`.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't made any accessors for your variables. Add these

```
attr_accessor :text
attr_accessor :number
```

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370960/what-is-attr-accessor-in-ruby)