# How to let `self` work in a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to downcase a user's email address before saving it to database in rails. I am at [this page](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users) using this code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save {self.email = email.downcase}
end
```

It also works if I write `self.email = self.email.downcase`, but it doesn't work if I write `email = email.downcase`. Under which condition can `self` be omitted?

Comment: in the latter one,any error you found..?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`self` must *always* be supplied when wishing to use a setter<sup>1</sup> on the left-hand side of an assignment, e.g. `self.x = val` or `self.x += val`<sup>2</sup>.

`self` can be omitted for getters (which are just normal method calls) when there is not a local variable that shadows the method.

Expressions of the form `x = val` or `x += val` - that is to say, without `self` - *always* assign to the local variable `x`. In this case that means a value was being assigned to the local variable `email` (not to be confused with `self.email`), which was then discarded when the block exited.

---

<sup>1</sup> See [What is attr_accessor in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370960/what-is-attr-accessor-in-ruby) for how getters/setters are implemented.

<sup>2</sup> When ruby sees `self.x = y` it treats it like `self.__send__(:x=, y)`. That is, the setter (which is just a normal method with a trailing equals in the name) is called magically.

Comment: Just to demonstrate one example please... I was not aware of this fact. :)

Comment: May I add one simple example?.. That I do have to your answer.. :)

Comment: First demonstrate why the output is `nil`? for the code - `class Foo
  attr_accessor :x
  def bar
     x = 10
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.bar
p foo.x`

Comment: Then say what's the fix - `class Foo
  attr_accessor :x
  def bar
     self.x = 10
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.bar
p foo.x`

Comment: @ArupRakshit You may update my answer as you like. Or add your own. Leaning something new is cool :)

Comment: Its OK.. I wouldn't create any answer,as your one is enough...people who are interested can see the code in the comment itself..

Answer (score 1):

```
email = email.downcase
```

**Makes a new variable** that overwrites the class synthesis of `email`. My rule of thumb is to always prefix attributes with `self`. While Ruby allowys you to do either, this is part of the **POLS** or Principle Of Least Surprise. When you work with other developers it is better if they don't have to dig through your code, and just know that email is an attribute. Bottom line, **don't omit `self`**.

And for gods sake, space out your code a tad. Readability is key.

```
before_save { self.email.downcase! }
```

Comment: You can't have an explicit `self` for a `private` getter, though.