# Can't access class instance variable set in another module

Tags: ruby

I can't access class instance variable set in another module using the

```
instance_variable_set("@#{key_name}", key_value)
```

Like in the example below:

```
module Neo4jMapper
  module Node
    def self.included base
      base.extend NodeClassMethods
      base.send :prepend, NodeInstanceMethods
    end
  end

 module NodeInstanceMethods

   def initialize(prototype)
     # Set neo4jId
     @_id     = prototype["self"].split('/').last.to_i

     # Set properties
     for key in self.class.keys
       key_name = key[0]
       if prototype["data"].has_key?(key_name)
         key_value = prototype["data"][key_name] 
         instance_variable_set("@#{key_name}", key_value)
       end
     end
   end
 end 
end


class Person
  include Neo4jMapper::Node
  #....
end
```

Instantiation:

```
person = Person.create({:name => "neo4j_mapper", :email => "test@test.com"})
```

This sets the person object with @name = "test@test.com" (viewed from the debugger). But the following line does not work:

```
email = person.email # ERROR: undefined method `email' for #<Person:0x007fd2038b8508>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Instance variables are not visible outside the object, this is by design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `attr_accessor` to generate a getter and setter.

```
attr_accessor :email
```

**References**

- [What is `attr_accessor` in Ruby? | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4371458/1669208)
- [`attr_accessor` | Ruby Docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor)

Comment: I just figured it out. Thanks!