# No "name" method error but I have a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :content %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :content, :cols =>20, :rows => 20 %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>

<%= f.text_area :name %> line is causing the error. When I remove it, it works fine.
```

Above lines are for when creating a new status...when I click on the "new status" button, error shows up. please help. Thank you!

Comment: We need to see the 'form' line, the error, the exact line the error references, the model schema, and the 'new' action from the relevant controller.

Comment: is there any specific cause to define `<%= f.text_area :name %>` twice, in single `form`?

Comment: I suspect your form would be better suited to a text_field for `:name` anyway. Do you actually have a `name` attribute in your model?

Comment: It's not defined twice, I think he just made a mistake when posting the question.

Comment: Is "name" permitted in the controller? Rails 4 has new ways of restricting access to fields.

Answer (score 0):

The no method error either means you don't have a `name` attribute defined in the table, or you don't have the `name` method in your model

---

**attr_accessor**

You have to remember that Rails is basically a bunch of classes all strung together; and models use the [`attr_accessor`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370960/what-is-attr-accessor-in-ruby) ruby method to create the attributes of your objects

The ways you could fix your error are:

1. Ensure you have a `name` column (attribute) in your DB
2. Ensure your model is retrieving said `name` attribute (you're not using [`.select()`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-select))
3. Use `attr_accessor` to create a name attribute
4. Use [`alias_attribute`](http://apidock.com/rails/Module/alias_attribute) to create the `name` attribute from another

Without seeing your other code, this *should* help:

```
#app/models/model.rb
Class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessor :name
end
```