# Object variables cannot be empty?

Tags: ruby

```
class Foobar
  def initialize
    self.placeHolder = ''
  end
end

bbq = Foobar.new
```

When I run the following code I receive a `NoMethodError`. This is very confusing to me, why would I not be able to have an empty instance variable? I know I can have an empty class variable but how come when I include `self` it gives me this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is trying to call the `placeHolder=` method, which your class doesn't have.

```
@placeHolder = ''
```

should work for you.

Or, you could add this line to your class:

```
attr_accessor :placeHolder
```

It will automatically create a getter and setter method for you. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4371458/3124288) for a great explanation.

---

When you do `someObject.someName` in ruby, that always means call the `someName` method on `someObject`. (Now you can fake some other kinds of behaviors because you can define a `method_missing` method to handle when a method is called that doesn't exist.) So when you do `self.someName` that just means call the `someName` method on some instance of the class.

Comment: Ok cool. But why would self.identifier create a method at all? I come from Python background and that is how why we declare object variables there. Why would it automatically assume its a method?

Comment: Added a little bit more detail in the answer to hopefully cover your question

Answer (score 2):

You're attempting to call the instance method `placeHolder=` of the Foobar class. The Foobar class does not have this method, so it correctly gives you a NoMethodError. If you want to set an instance variable, the syntax for doing that is `@placeholder = ''`.  If instead you wish to have an accessor method, you'll need to either write one yourself or include `attr_accessor :placeHolder` in the class body.

(Incidentally, it is idiomatic in Ruby to use snake_case rather than camelCase.)

Answer (score 2):

This is because attr_accessors aren't defined in class Foobar.

```
attr_accessor :placeholder
```