# Rails undefined method `email' in method update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, methods, undefined

I have model Produit that i want to update in controller ProduitsController.
When i try to update i get the following error : 
 -NoMethodError in ProduitsController#update
 -undefined method `email' for #

I don't have attribute email for this model (ProduitsController) and i don't know why the update methode call method email???
Is some one can please help me or give me any information?

```
----------here the line the error in file produits_controllers.rb-----------------------

         ##   require 'debugger'; debugger
            respond_to do |format|
    error linge ==>if @produit.update(produit_params)
                format.html { redirect_to @produit, notice: 'produit was successfully updated.' }
                format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @produit }
              else 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

controllers/produits_controllers.rb

```
  class ProduitsController < ApplicationController
          before_action :set_produit, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

      # GET /totos
      # GET /totos.json
      def index
        @produits = Produit.all
      end

      # GET /totos/1
      # GET /totos/1.json
      def show
      end

      # GET /totos/new
      def new
        @produit = Produit.new
        @etatproduits = Etatproduit.all
        @magasins = Magasin.all
      end

      # GET /totos/1/edit
      def edit
        @etatproduits = Etatproduit.all
        @magasins = Magasin.all
      end

      # POST /totos
      # POST /totos.json
      def create
         @produit = Produit.new(produit_params)

         respond_to do |format|
           if @produit.save
             format.html { redirect_to @produit, notice: 'produit was successfully created.' }
             format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @produit }
           else
             format.html { render :new }
             format.json { render json: @produit.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
           end
        end
      end

      # PATCH/PUT /totos/1
      # PATCH/PUT /totos/1.json
      def update
     ##   require 'debugger'; debugger
        respond_to do |format|
          if @produit.update(produit_params)
            format.html { redirect_to @produit, notice: 'produit was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @produit }
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
            format.json { render json: @produit.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # DELETE /totos/1
      # DELETE /totos/1.json
      def destroy
        @produit.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
         format.html { redirect_to produits_url, notice: 'produit was successfully destroyed.' }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end

      private
        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def set_produit
          @produit = Produit.find(params[:id])
        end

        # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
        def produit_params
           params.require(:produit).permit(:nom, :etatproduit_id, :last_change_stat, :magasin_id)
        end
    end
```

---

models/produit.rb

```
class Produit < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, 
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
    belongs_to :magasin
    belongs_to :etatproduit
end
```

---

migrate/20140629085947_create_produits.rb

```
   class CreateProduits < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :produits do |t|
          t.string :nom
          t.datetime :last_change_stat

          t.timestamps
          t.belongs_to :etatproduit
          t.belongs_to :magasin
        end

        add_index :produits, :nom
        add_index :produits, :etatproduit_id, unique: true
      end
    end
```

---

log error

```
Started PATCH "/produits/1" for 192.168.56.1 at 2014-07-30 01:11:18 +0000
Processing by ProduitsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"TNgQiTyu2tVnah42G9CcfupzxV9pfCGYVKo9ehWYzXA=", "produit"=>{"nom"=>"dfbdfbfdfffd", "etatproduit_id"=>"2", "magasin_id"=>"3"}, "commit"=>"Save", "id"=>"1"}
  Produit Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `produits`.* FROM `produits`  WHERE `produits`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 6ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `email' for #<Produit:0x000000097a6ff8>):
  app/controllers/produits_controller.rb:49:in `block in update'
  app/controllers/produits_controller.rb:48:in `update'


  Rendered /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (1.4ms)
  Rendered /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.2ms)
  Rendered /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.8ms)
  Rendered /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (19.6ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Devise**

Further to `Jaugar`'s answer, the error is almost certainly a result of `Devise`

You've included `Devise` in your `Produit` model here:

```
#app/models/produit.rb
class Produit < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, 
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
```

As mentioned, I don't know *why* you've got Devise in this model, but  if we consider you *want* it in there, you have to make sure you have the accompanying attributes Devise requires (`:email` being one)

The *immediate* fix (hack) for this is to use [`attr_accessor`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370960/what-is-attr-accessor-in-ruby) to create a "virtual" attribute for `email`, and other `Devise` attributes:

```
#app/models/produit.rb
class Produit < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, 
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessor :email, :other, :devise, :attributes
```

This will not fix the problem - just mask it.

--

**Solution**

The solution to this is to either add the required attributes to your table, or to remove `Devise` from your `Produit` model

Considering, as `Jaugar` suggested, `Devise` is best served on the `User` model - I would *highly* recommend removing it from your `Produit` model. If you want to create `authentication` functionality for your application, you'll be best creating a `User` model to mount `Devise` onto

Comment: Tx for you help. i have remouve device attribute in my model and it work. ^^

Answer (score 1):

Why you add devise into produit model ?

Devise is usally add into User model, so user model need email attribute.

You should read more document about Devise.

If you really want add devise into produit model, you can add email attribute like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :timeoutable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :user_name
end
```