# Difference between attribute and attr_accessor in ActiveAttr gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attr-accessor, active-attr

I'm trying to use the active_attr gem to create models backed by a NoSQL database that doesn't seem to have any other ORMs or mappers that fit our needs.

In the documentation (https://github.com/cgriego/active_attr), it shows examples defining attribtues with just `attribute` and sometimes using `attr_accessor`. I'm not quite sure I see the difference. Can someone explain when I should use one over the other?

Answer (score 4):

[`attr_accessor`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370960/what-is-attr-accessor-in-ruby) is a Ruby method, `attribute` is a custom method for `active_attr`.

For example:

```
class User
  include ActiveAttr::QueryAttributes
  attribute :first_name
end

User.new.first_name?
```

In the above, `attribute :first_name` will use `attr_accessor` to create basic getters/setters (`first_name` and `first_name=`), and then additionally add at least another method `first_name?`.

It appears `attr_accessor` is used alongside modules that augment the Class (`MassAssignment`, `BlockInitialization`), whereas `attribute` is used for modules that directly augment attributes of the Class instances.