# Can't access custom Exception attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, exception

I've got a custom Exception class declared like so:

```
class CustomError < StandardError
  def initialize(message = nil)
    @message = message
    @type = "custom_error"
  end
end
```

That is being handled in my Application controller like so:

```
rescue_from CustomError do |e|
  render json: e.type
end
```

Now, when I raise the Exception using `raise CustomError.new("Oops I did it again")` I get a `NoMethodError` with *undefined method `type'*

What's going on? Why can't I just access `type` using `e.type`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was missing `attr_reader`. Here's what the final `Exception` class looks like:

```
class CustomError < StandardError
  attr_reader :type

  def initialize(message = nil)
    @message = message
    @type = "custom_error"
  end
end
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4371458/2022751

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `e.type` because you haven't defined a `type` method.

You can use

```
attr_reader :type
```

To add such an accessor.