# How does the send method work without any symbol?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I do not understand how `send` works in the following code as it's using no symbol. How come it manages to return the values of the attributes?

Here is the code:

```
module FormatAttributes
    def formats(*attributes)
        @format_attributes = attributes
    end

    def format_attributes
        @format_attributes
    end
end

module Formatter
    def display
        self.class.format_attributes.each do |attribute|
            puts "[#{attribute.to_s.upcase}] #{send(attribute)}"
        end
    end
end

class Resume
    extend FormatAttributes
    include Formatter
    attr_accessor :name, :phone_number, :email, :experience
    formats :name, :phone_number, :email, :experience
end

resume = Resume.new
resume.name = "Superman"
resume.email = "superman@gmail.com"
resume.phone_number = "12345"
resume.experience = "Ruby"

resume.display
```

The outcome being:

```
[NAME] Superman
[PHONE_NUMBER] 12345
[EMAIL] superman@gmail.com
[EXPERIENCE] Ruby
```

Comment: You should format your code better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please read the [`send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Object.html#method-i-send) method's documentation. It says:

> Invokes the method identified by symbol, passing it any arguments specified. You can use **send** if the name send clashes with an existing method in obj. When the method is identified by a string, the string is converted to a symbol.

Now, you have included `Formatter` module and used `extend` for `FormatAttributes` module in your `Resume` class. Needless to say, which actually makes `display` method from `Formatter` an instance method. Also, `formats`, and `format_attributes` from `FormatAttributes` will be available as class methods for your `Resume` class. Now, your display method:

```
    def display
        self.class.format_attributes.each do |attribute|
            puts "[#{attribute.to_s.upcase}] #{send(attribute)}"
        end
    end
```

calls `format_attributes` which is a `class` method hence you do: `self.class.format_attributes` and since this method is suppose to return an array of attributes, which are passed as symbols:

```
formats :name, :phone_number, :email, :experience
```

Hence:

```
@format_attributes = [:name, :phone_number, :email, :experience]
```

Now in `each` block with `attribute`, you have:

```
puts "[#{attribute.to_s.upcase}] #{send(attribute)}"
```

Which can be translated to, for an instance:

```
puts "[#{:name.to_s.upcase}] #{send(:name)}"
```

Hence, `name` will be called on the instance method of `Resume` class and that's why you see all that output.

**EDIT**: Why `:name`, `:phone_number`, `:email`, and `:experience` are available as method?

It's because of this line:

```
attr_accessor :name, :phone_number, :email, :experience
```

Read more about [`attr_accessor` here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370960/what-is-attr-accessor-in-ruby).

Comment: It makes it a lot clearer already, thanks a lot. However, I still miss a little something to fully get the concept. I do not understand how `:name` is a method in itself, which from what I got of the send method syntax should be the case to make it work (following the syntax `send(:method_to_call)`). Based on my understanding at that point, `attr_accessor(:name)` is a method allows to assign value to an instance variable `@name` of name and read it. I do not get how `:name` manages to be kind of "standalone". Am I making myself clear ? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: It's because of this line: `attr_accessor :name, :phone_number, :email, :experience` it actually defines the passed symbols as methods as reader and writer.

Comment: Thanks, got it. PS : I read the send documentation before posting, just did not get how it works.

Comment: No worries, I added explanation on `:name` and other attributes behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You pass `attribute` variable as argument, which probably contains `Symbol` or `String` object.

Comment: @AntoineBoillot what exactly is blurry?

Comment: Sorry but this is still blurry to me. Here, the "attribute" is an element of the array "attributes", each attribute being a variable that comes with its definition and value. could you please describe with one example, for instance, how we get from "attribute" to "superman" here" Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`self.class.format_attributes` accessor will fetch `@format_attributes` on the class object, which was set to `[:name, :phone_number, :email, :experience]` by the `formats` line.

As you iterate `attribute` over it, it will get the values `:name`, then `:phone_number`, etc.
Thus, inside the `each` loop, you will perform `send(:name)`, `send(:phone_number)` etc.

When `attribute` has value `:name` in the first iteration, `send(attribute)` will do the same thing as `send(:name)`, which does the same as `name`, which will return `"Superman"`.

Comment: It makes it a lot clearer already, thanks a lot. However, I still miss a little something to fully get the concept. I do not understand how `:name` is a method in itself, which from what I got of the send method syntax should be the case to make it work (following the syntax `send(:method_to_call)`). For, based on my understanding at that point, `attr_accessor(:name)` is a method allows to assign value to an instance variable `@name` of name and read it. I do not get how `:name`manages to be kind of "standalone". Am I making myself clear ? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: `:name` is a symbol (a value). `attribute` is a variable that (at one point in time) contains that value, just like when you do `x = 5`, variable `x` contains an integer value `5`. There are also methods called `name` and `name=` on the class `Resume`, which were defined by `attr_accessor :name`. `:name` is not a method, it is the *name* of the method `Resume#name`. You can execute this method either directly, by `self.name` (equivalent to just `name`), or by using the `send` method, `self.send(:name)` (equivalent to `send(:name)`), which invokes the method with name `:name` (which is `name`).

Comment: Very clear, thank you. From my understanding, `:name` is also the name of the method `Resume#name=`. Hope it is not a stupid question, but how does the system manages to know that invoking the method with name `:name` should refer to `name`and not `name=`. Is that because, `name=`has already been used in `resume.name = "Superman"`? Thanks

Comment: No, the symbol name of `Resume#name=` is `:name=`.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on the latter, even though it seems semantically logic : the only used symbol here is `:name` along with the `attr_accessor` method. As a result, this defines two methods, respectively `name` and `name=`. This being done using one symbole only (`:name`), how come the `:name=` even exists here ?

Comment: `attr_accessor(symbol)` will define two methods: a getter named `:"#{symbol}"`, and a setter named `:"#{symbol}="`. `attr_reader` only creates the former, `attr_writer` only defines the latter.

Comment: Crystal clear. Now I fully understand everything. Thanks a lot for your time @Amadan