# How to add custom name input field in rails simple_form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, simple-form

`@tech_data = TagNode.first` outputs below object from the controller .

```
p @tech_data
#<TagNode _id: 5119dcf74054448e576f3392, parent_id: nil, parent_ids: [], name: "categories", path: "categories", _type: "TagNode">
```

I have a form which has the fields `name`, `_type`, and `category`. But my object doesn't have the field `category`.

Here's my form

```
  = simple_form_for @tech_data, as: :techtags, :url => view_techtags_technologies_path, :remote => true,:method => :get,:html => {:id => "upsert_techtags",:data => {:spinner => "#tech-ui"}} do |f|
  %label.pull-left Type
  = f.input :_type, :collection => tech_types, :label => false, :input_html => {:class =>"chzn-select", :data => {:placeholder => "Select Technology Type"}, :multiple => false}
  %label.pull-left Name
  = f.input :name, :type=>"text", :required => true, :label => false, :placeholder =>"Type the New Technology", :input_html => {:style => "width:265px;margin-bottom:0;"}
  %label.pull-left Category
  = f.input :category, :collection => [1,2,3,4], :label => false, :input_html => {:class =>"chzn-select", :disabled=>"true",:data => {:placeholder => "Type or select category"}, :multiple => false}
  = f.submit "Create", :class => "btn btn-primary pull-right"
```

My form has an additional field that my object doesn't have. I get an error when the form is loaded, as I don't have `category` field in my object.

How can I select the `category` value in the form without adding this field to the model?

Answer (score 0):

You need something like attr_accessor in Ruby,[What is attr_accessor in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370960/what-is-attr-accessor-in-ruby) 
Please include following in your model,which will make to get values from form to controller.
attr_accessor :category

Comment: Manoj. His post reads that he doesn't want to `include/modify` anything in the modal

Comment: it seems like he meant, he dont want to add the field to table.

Comment: Manoj is right, attr_accessor simply means the attribute can be get/set by the model, is has nothing to do with the database..