# Metaprogramming in Ruby with derived classes

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I'm trying to write a method that prints class variable names and their values. As an example:

```
class A
    def printvars
        ???
    end
end

class <<A
    def varlist(*args)
        ???
    end
end

class B < A
    varlist :c
    def initialize(c)
        @c = c
    end
b = B.new(10)
b.printvars()
```

And I would like the output to be `c => 10`.  But I don't know what goes in the `???`.  I've tried using a `self.class_eval` in the body of varlist, but that won't let me store `args`.  I've also tried keeping a hash in the class `A` and just printing it out in `printvars`, but the singleton class is a superclass of `A` and so has no access to this hash. So far everything I've tried doesn't work.

I think something similar must be possible, since Rails does something related with its validates_* methods. Ideally I could make this work exactly as expected, but even a pointer to how to print *just* the variable names (so just `c` as output) would be most appreciated.

Comment: Can you say more about what you're trying to do? Also, have you looked at things like `awesome_print` or `pry`?

Comment: Also, it's very unconventional to define class methods like `class <<A`. You can do `def self.varlist(*args)` inside the original `class A` definition.

Comment: My end goal here is to understand how validates_* works.

Answer (score 1):

You might like this answer: [What is attr_accessor in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370960/what-is-attr-accessor-in-ruby)

Basically, as you surmised, `varlist` needs to be a class method which takes a variable list of arguments (`*args`). Once you have those arguments you could try any number of things using `send`, `respond_to?`, or maybe even `instance_variable_get`. Note, none of those are really recommended, but I wanted to answer your question a bit.

The other half is that you should probably look into `method_missing` in order to understand how things like `validates_*` are working. The * part necessitates that you do something like `method_missing` because you can't actually do module_eval until you know what you're looking for. In the case of the magic rails methods, you don't necessarily *ever* know what you're looking for! So we rely on the built in `method_missing` to let us know what got called.

For funzies, try this in IRB:

```
class A
  def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
    puts method, args.inspect
  end
end
A.new.banana(13, 'snakes')
A.new.validates_serenity_of('Scooters', :within => [:calm, :uncalm])
```

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks that is actually very helpful. My followup question is then how to replace the puts in method_missing with something more permanent?  That is,  how does validates :snakes,  in: [1,2,3] store the name snakes,  store the array to check it again during save,  and also access the value of snakes when in save?

Comment: Yeah, when I woke up this morning realizing that I hadn't actually answered your question. Probably you'd use `module_eval`. The problem I didn't talk about is that I used the instance version of `method_missing`, if you try it with the class version you'll note that `validates_*` gets called before anything. So that's where you'd use a singleton variable (which is also @variable_name, but when @ is used outside a method it's stored on the class instance (aka the singleton). Later, inside an instance, you'll use `self.class.variable_name` or something.

Answer (score 1):

### Just use Module#class_variables

As far as I can tell, you're vastly over-complicating this. All you need is the pre-defined [Module#class_variables](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-class_variables) method. You can call this directly on the class, or invoke it through *self* if you want to bind it to an instance of the class. For example:

```
class Foo
  @@bar = "baz"

  def show_class_variables
    self.class.class_variables
  end
end

Foo.class_variables
#=> [:@@bar]

foo = Foo.new
foo.show_class_variables
#=> [:@@bar]
```

Comment: I think that perhaps my example above didn't explain everything fully. But I want to be able to add select variables to a "watchlist" .