# Setters and Getter in ruby

Tags: ruby, eclipse

How do I automatically generate setters and getters for a node class in ruby? I am using eclipse

```
class Node

  def initialize(*args)

    if args.size > 2 or args.size < 1
        raise "initializer needs 0,1 or 2 arguments"    
    elseif args.size == 1
      @data = args[0] 
    else
      @data = args[0]
      @next = args[1]   
    end
  end

  def to_s

  end
end
```

Comment: Hello guys, how do I automatically generate setters and getters for a node class in ruby? I am using eclipse

Comment: Yikes! -8 in just 17 minutes. Call Guinness! Moral: never, ever, post a question and walk away. Also, to clarify, edit the question rather than try to explain in comments.

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic Ruby approach would be [`attr_accessor :data, :next`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370960/what-is-attr-accessor-in-ruby) (also see ["What is an accessor?](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/accessors.html)).

Then when, and only when, custom behavior was required would an overload / explicit method implementation be added. Ruby is not Java; don't need to add boilerplate code to everything.

If desiring to "see the code anyway" then a [custom template can be added](http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/effective-eclipse-custom-templ) to Eclipse. The `attr_accessor` links above explain how such a template ought to look to mimic the `attr_*` behaviors.