# Passing variables between classes in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I am trying to figure out how to pass variables between classes in Ruby. The example I am working on now is a game, where the players health, equipment, etc keeps changing and is passed from scene to scene until the game is over. Here is what I have so far:

```
class Player
  def enter()
  end
end

class MyPlayer < Player
  def initialize()
    dog_biscuits = false
  end
end

class Scene
  def enter()
  end
end

class Entrance < Scene
  def enter(player)
    puts "You are in the entrance"
    if player.dog_biscuits == false
      puts "You don't have any biscuits."
    end
  end
end

player = MyPlayer.new
entrance = Entrance.new
entrance.enter(player)
```

Whenever I run this, I get the following error message:

```
entrance.rb:20:in `enter': undefined method `dog_biscuits' for #<MyPlayer:0x007fbfe2167f20> (NoMethodError)
```

I am running ruby 2.2.3p173 on OSX El Capitan.

Comment: The "passing around" bit is working fine. You just messed up the `dog_biscuits` part. In your code it's a local variable. And you mean for it to be an `attr_accessor`. Google up some example for this keyword.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4371458/125816

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
class MyPlayer < Player
  attr_accessor :dog_biscuits
  def initialize()
    @dog_biscuits = false
  end
end
```

Using `attr_accessor` will allow you to set and get instance variables. Remember also that you have to prefix instance variables with `@`.

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyPlayer < Player

  def initialize()
    @dog_biscuits = false
  end

  def has_no_dog_biscuits?
    @dog_biscuits == false
  end
end
```

It is better to create method `has_no_dog_biscuits?` then to have `attr_reader` and to expose attribute to outer world, this way, you can always check if player has not dog_biscuits.