# How to check ruby attributes with an `if` statement

Tags: ruby, oop, if-statement, attributes

I am trying to build a console elevator simulator in OOP. I declared three attributes: `currentFloor`, `minFloor` and `maxFloor` with `attr_accessor`.

In `currentFloor` reader method, how can I check if the value is greater than `maxFloor` or lower than `minFloor`?

Comment: please show some code

Answer (score 1):

As per your given requirement I have a solution that would help you.

You can define this way

```
class Elevator
  attr_accessor :current_floor, :min_floor, :max_floor

  def initialize(current_floor, min_floor, max_floor)
    @current_floor = current_floor
    @min_floor = min_floor
    @max_floor = max_floor
  end

end
```

Now you can assign the values to the all three attr_accessor

```
elevator = Elevator.new(100,150,500)
```

and now check get the values of the attr_accessor and also you check the condition whatever you want

```
if elevator.current_floor > elevator.max_floor
  // perform operation here
else
  // perform operation here
end
```

If you still have any query please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

refer [What is attr_accessor in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370960/what-is-attr-accessor-in-ruby)  for the different of the:

`attr_accessor`: define default getter and setter

`attr_reader`: define default getter

`attr_writer`: define default setter

depends on what you need, you should customise the getter or setter, In your example, if you want to customise your reader method:

```
class Elevator
  attr_writer :currentFloor
  def currentFloor
    if some_condition_check
      raise error
    end
    currentFloor
  end
end
```

But more often, you should customise your setter instead of getter, in which case:

```
class Elevator
  attr_reader :currentFloor
  def currentFloor=(current)
    if some_condition_check
      raise error
    end
    @currentFloor = current
  end
end
```