# Ruby on Rails:Get params with attribute which not in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a field which is not in my model, but it is in my `_form.html.erb` . Now i want to get it from form, but i get this error :

```
undefined method 'description' for Object
```

My controller:

```
def job_params
@job_params ||=params.permit(:description) # (description is not an attribute in job model ).
```

How can i get description ??
My form:

```
<%= form_for(@job) do |f| %>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :description %><br>
  <%= f.text_field :description %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `attr_accessor` in your model for `description`.

```
class DummyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor: description
end
```

[Reference](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Model.html)

You might also look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370960/what-is-attr-accessor-in-ruby#4371458) one.