# When creating an instance of a class, how do attr_accessor methods get attached?

Tags: ruby

In the docs for [Class](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Class.html) it says:

```
class Name
    # some code describing the class behavior
end
```

> When a new Class is created, an object of type Class is initialized and assigned to a global constant (Name in this case).
>
> When Name.new is called to create a new object, the new method in Class is run by default.

There is also this diagram

```
                     +---------+             +-...
                     |         |             |
     BasicObject-----|-->(BasicObject)-------|-...
         ^           |         ^             |
         |           |         |             |
      Object---------|----->(Object)---------|-...
         ^           |         ^             |
         |           |         |             |
         +-------+   |         +--------+    |
         |       |   |         |        |    |
         |    Module-|---------|--->(Module)-|-...
         |       ^   |         |        ^    |
         |       |   |         |        |    |
         |     Class-|---------|---->(Class)-|-...
         |       ^   |         |        ^    |
         |       +---+         |        +----+
         |                     |
obj--->OtherClass---------->(OtherClass)-----------...
```

If I create an instance of Name:

```
class Name
    attr_accessor :foo
    # some code describing the class behavior
end

n = Name.new
```

How is it that the object `n` ends up with the method `n.foo`?

At first I thought `attr_accessor` was a method of type Object but looking at the docs it is actually of Module and I don't see anywhere that says Module is mixed in to Object.

Then I thought that since Class inherits from Module and when `Name.new` is called, which I assume `new` is a method on the initialized object of type Class, it will create an instance of Name and also call `attr_accessor` in the Module? But the docs for `attr_accessor` say,

> Defines a named attribute for this module

Does that mean there is also a module created at the same time? How does it then relate to my Name instance?

Comment: Though interesting, I feel there is more than one question being asked here.

Comment: I think it's a lot more question than the OP wants an answer for. It's one of those things that's good to accept as "it just works", until farther up the learning curve.

Comment: I'd suggest reading this possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/4370960/128421

Comment: Its been a while, the missing link was in @theTinMan post, that says Ruby classes are evaluated and that is when the `attr_accessor` is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing gets attached anywhere. `attr_accessor` is simply defined more or less like this:

```
class Module
  def attr_accessor(*names)
    names.each do |name|
      define_method(name)        do       instance_variable_get(:"@#{name}"     )
      define_method(:"#{name}=") do |val| instance_variable_set(:"@#{name}", val)
    end
  end
end
```

That's all there is to it.