# Ruby, what is this output if not an array or hash?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

As the title states, what is this output? I tried checking if it's an array or a hash with `nextPart.to_a(Hash)?` and `nextPart.kind_of?(Array)`, using both Hash and Array and result is always false.

So what is this output and how do I get and change variables like @rotated?

```
#<JoMojo_cutz::Cutz::SheetPart:0x0000000ed2c658 @rotated=false, @append=false>
```

I've tried... and a few other variations with no luck...

```
nextPart.rotated
nextPart[rotated]
nextPart[@rotated]
```

Comment: It is a `JoMojo_cutz::Cutz::SheetPart` instance (ie. an object that is not an Array or Hash). [@variables are instance variables](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/instancevars.html). While one *can* use [`#instance_variable_set`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set), it would be better to *Read the documentation* to find out how the API is designed to work.

Comment: I count 21 instance variables. Is it not possible to give an example with fewer, perhaps `@rotated` and one other?

Comment: @CarySwoveland sorry for the length of the example, I just cut and paste the output without realizing it's length. Edited the example. Noticed you're a woodworker, so am I, and I'm learning ruby so I can try and modify a sketchup cut sheet plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always write `nextPart.instance_variable_get("@rotated")` or `nextPart.instance_variable_set("@rotated", "new value")`

But it's better to add `attr_accessor :rotated` to the class - then you can do `nextPart.rotated` and `nextPart.rotated = "new value"`.

For each of the instance variables you want to define these dot-methods for, you can add it to the `attr_accessor`:

```
attr_accessor :rotated, :thickness
# etc.
```

See [What is attr_accessor in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370960/what-is-attr-accessor-in-ruby)

Also, keep in mind there are many classes in Ruby. You can call `nextPart.class` to see what it is. In this case, you can tell from this that it's a `JoMojo_cutz::Cutz::SheetPart`:

```
#<JoMojo_cutz::Cutz::SheetPart:0x0000000ed2c658
```

This is kind of a Rubyism that you can just come to recognize. When you see

```
#<ClassName:ObjectId
```

you can just know that it's an instance.

Comment: Appreciate the explanation, right after I posted my question a found that exact question about attr_accessor. I've gotten lucky so far learning ruby by modifying and studying other's code but this particular code is a mess and a real pain to try and figure out!