# Understanding Ruby Setters

Tags: ruby

If I create a class like this:

```
class Player

  def initialize(position, name)
    @position = position
    @name = name
  end

end
```

Isn't that setting the name to an instance variable? if so, why would I need to write a setter like this

```
 class Player

  def initialize(position, name)
    @position = position
    @name = name
  end

  def name=(name)
    @name = name
  end

 end
```

Basically when is it necessary to write getters in a class?

Comment: Your examples are all about *setters*, but your "basically" summary talks about *getters*. Is that a typo, or intentional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getters and setters job is to provide you a quick implementation of read and write of instance variables that you define in your constructor:

```
class Player
  attr_accessor :name, :position
  def initialize(position, name)
    @position = position
    @name = name
  end
end
```

you can also user `attr_reader`(for getters) and `attr_writer`(for setters) specifically for these variables.

Above code: `attr_accessor :name, :position` gives you: `#name`, `#position`, `#name=`, and `#position=` methods for instance of `Player` class.

However, they're not going to give you validation or a customized logic for getters/setters.

For example: you might want to show a player's full name or do not wish your code to accept a 0 or negative position, in such a case you'd have to write getter and setter yourself:

```
class Player
  def initialize(first_name, last_name, position)
    @first_name = first_name
    @last_name = last_name
    @position = position
  end

  # validation for updating position using setter of position
  def position=(new_position)
    raise "invalid position: #{new_position}" if new_position <= 0
    @position = new_position
  end

  # customized getter for name method
  def name
    "#{@first_name} #{@last_name}"
  end
end
```

If you do not require customization as stated above then using `attr_*` method for these variables makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

`initialize` sets attributes during the *initialization* of a new object.

```
keeper = Player.new('goalkeeper','Shilton').
```

What if you want to update an attribute of `keeper` after initialzation? Well you'll need to use your ordinary setter method:

```
def name=(name)
  @name = name
end
```

like so:

```
keeper.name = 'Banks'
```

If you don't have a setter method defined for Player instances, then you can't do this. Similarly for getter methods. Also be aware you can refactor your code by using [attr_accessor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4371458/5101493) like so:

```
class Player
  attr_accessor :name, :position

  def initialize(position, name)
    @position = position
    @name = name
  end    
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Getters/setters, also known as "accessors", are accessible outside the class, instance variables are not. If you want things to be able to read or change `@name` from *outside* the class, you to define accessors for it.

Additionally accessor methods allow you to perform a certain amount of sanity checking or mutate incoming/outgoing values, and otherwise protect the internal state of your objects.