# Rails 4.2.6 adding extra attributes to activerecord elements

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, model

I want to add extra fields to the results of a query without first converting to JSON.

I have 3 models `team`, `tournament` and `match`, with the following relationship:

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :homeTeam, class_name: "Team", foreign_key: "localTeam"
   belongs_to :awayTeam, class_name: "Team", foreign_key: "visitorTeam"

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :local_matches, class_name: "Match", foreign_key: "localTeam"
   has_many :visitor_matches, class_name: "Match", foreign_key: "visitorTeam"

class Tournament < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :matches, class_name:"Match",foreign_key: "tournamentId"
```

In the `Tournament` class, I'm trying to add a function that will give me a list of all matches in the tournamet, but for each match it should include some data from the`Team`s involved in it (homeTeam and awayTeam).

I'm trying the following:

```
def tournament_matches
 matches= self.matches
 matches.each do |match|
  match[:home_team_logo] = match.homeTeam.logo //add this field
  match[:visitor_team_logo] = match.awayTeam.logo //add this field
 end
 matches.group_by(:round)
end
```

But I get an error:
`ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute 'local_team_name'`

What can I do so that I can add extra fields from `Team` to my `ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy` `Match` class elements in the return? Keep in mind that `Team.logo` is a function, not an attribute.

Answer (score 1):

you can use attr_accessor in Team Model and store values in it. It creates a virtual field which doesn't exists in Database but you will be able to access it using `match.homeTeam.<attribute_name>`. you can read about attr_accessor here:

> [What is attr_accessor in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370960/what-is-attr-accessor-in-ruby)
>
> https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/attr_accessor