# ruby about attr_accessor, instance variables, local varibles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm so confused about that..
like this

```
class Box 
   attr_accessor :item ,:item2  

   def initialize(item2)
      @item = []
      @item2 = item2
   end

   def add(product)
      item << product
   end

   def empty?
      item.empty?
   end

   def increment(n=1)
      item2 +=1
   end

end

cart =Box.new(123)
cart.add(1)
puts cart.empty? #false
puts cart.item   #1
```

in the 'add' and 'empty?' methods
I use local variable 'item' right?
why I can get the value from @items ??

and I try this

```
cart.item2 = 345
puts cart.item2  #345
puts cart.increment #'increment': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

now I can't get the value?

please fix my brain thx

Comment: `item` is the method defined with `attr_accessor`.

Comment: because of attr_accessor , I call item method in add method and insert product?

Comment: Hello! It's been all said you call the accessors when you don't add the @ of the instance variable. That's why your call to increment fails, because `item2`is a return value and not a variable, so it doesn't have a `+=` method. (Can't explain exactly why it tries to call it on Nil though). For example if I replace `item2 +=1` with `item2 + 1` I have no error and it returns `346` (You can't actually increment the instance variable because `item2` returns the value, and not the variable).

Comment: Luke, you need to read about what `attr_accessor` is doing and how `self` works in Ruby.

Comment: wow, thank u guys, u made it all clear

Comment: `cart = Box.new(123,"")` should result in `ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1))`

Comment: oh sorry. it should be Box.new(123), it's was item3  in the class, item3 is String variable . i was trying what's different. I got the same result like item2. so i delete item3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4371458/5961578), which is the most-upvoted Ruby post in StackOverflow history. It will help you understand `attr_accessor` and its cousins `attr_reader` and `attr_writer`.

Besides that, your code has many problems.

First, you should not name an Array with a singular variable name like `item`. Use a plural `items` to make its purpose clear.

Second, the name `item2` is not good. For your attribute, use something descriptive like `counter`, and for the variable passed as an argument to initialize it, let's use something descriptive like `initial_count`.

Third, your `increment` method takes an optional argument but then ignores it. Wouldn't it be surprising if someone called `box.increment(2)` and the attribute was incremented by only 1? The intent of this method is to use `counter += n` instead of `counter += 1`.

Fourth, to set `counter` from within the class, we need to use `self`. So instead of `counter += n`, we have to do `self.counter += n`.

Finally, consider whether you want the attributes to be readable and writable from an outside source, or whether you want to reserve write privileges to the object itself. Because you have methods to add things to `items` and to increment `counter`, you probably want to conceal write privileges. I would use `attr_reader` publicly and `attr_writer` privately.

Incorporating these suggestions, here's the resulting code:

```
class Box
  attr_reader :counter, :items

  def initialize(initial_count)
    @counter = initial_count
    @items = []
  end

  def add(product)
    items << product
  end

  def empty?
    items.empty?
  end

  def increment(n = 1)
    self.counter += n
  end

  private

  attr_writer :counter, :items
end
```

Now you can do this, all of which makes sense, more or less:

```
>> cart = Box.new(123)
>> cart.increment(2)
>> cart.counter
#> 125
>> cart.add('A product')
>> cart.add('Another product')
>> cart.items
#> ["A product", "Another product"]
```

But if you try to set `counter` or `items` directly, you'll get an error:

```
>> cart.counter = 1
#> NoMethodError: private method `counter=' called for #<Box:0x007fc13e17dc50>
```

Comment: Overkill, but a good explanation. Though, could you chose between `@attribute` and `self.attribute` instead of mixing them?

Comment: @CyrilLemaire Where/how am I mixing them? I'm not using `@attribute` anywhere but in the constructor.

Comment: Well then I might just be stupid, but what's the point of changing the syntax between the constructor and the other methods?

Comment: @CyrilLemaire I use the constructor to initialize instance variables, and then I access them via the setter/getter methods created by `attr_reader` and `attr_writer`. "Real" OO programming, so the argument goes, is about objects sending messages to objects. So the object sets its variables once, and then those variables are viewed or changed only as a result of the messages (internal and external) sent to the object. There are differing viewpoints, as outlined [here](https://forum.upcase.com/t/using-instance-variables-vs-attribute-accessors/1788/9). But I like sending messages.

Comment: Ahhh, ok thanks! I thought `@` was just a shortcut for `self.` while `self.` only refers to methods, and `@`to attributes !

Comment: @CyrilLemaire Here's another [good discussion](http://ambertunnell.github.io/blog/2014/06/29/analyzing-instance-variables-in-ruby/). Do yourself a favor and get a copy of [Practical Object-Oriented Design in Ruby](http://www.poodr.com) by Sandi Metz.

Comment: ".. the variable name item2 is not good". Is variable the correct term here?

Comment: @SagarPandya It's both a variable (as an argument) and a method/attribute. And it's not good for either one. But I take your point. See edited answer.

Comment: thank mate. you improve my code. actually, I knew attr_accessor make variable have getter and setter.  so variable has `def variable` and  def  `variable=` , but I misunderstood it. I thought it is local variable.  you guys make me clear. thanks again