# ruby on rail - problem with attr_accessor in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a newbie rails programer and i have a problem when get data. My User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
attr_accessor :name
```

My UserController

```
@users = User.all
```

My view users/index.html.erb

```
 <% @users.each do |user| %>
<%= user.name %> //error: undefined method `name`
```

but if i remove attr_accessor :name in User model, my app is run.
Please, tell me what is wrong

My rails version is 5.

Comment: In your view before `<%= user.name %>`, put a debugger and see what is the value of `user`, does it have the attribute `name` ?

Comment: <%= user[:name] %> it work but <%= user.name %> it error

Comment: Can you try creating a new `user` and in your index action, see what is the values of `@users`, before iterating in the views. According to **Rails**, `attr_accessor` is a method called on the **current class**, and `:name` is a parameter you pass to that method.

Comment: You do not need to use `attr_accessor` in a Rails model to access it's attributes.

Comment: so, if i remove attr_accessor :name, what is changed in my app?

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna tks.

Comment: attr_accessor is a class level method. While you are trying to use it on an instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

attr_accessor is a class level method. You are trying to use it on an instance level.

Try `cattr_accessor` instead. Although you dont need an `attr_accessor` or`cattr_accessor` to access attributes of an`ActiveRecord::Base` model that are defined in the schema.

### ====> EDIT <==== Corrected Answer Below

Disregard the advice above. It's not accurate. Im leaving it for reference. The reason you are getting the `undefined method: name` error is because you have set an `attr_accessor` on a model that already has a getter set dynamically via `ActiveRecord::Base`.

Setting `attr_accessor` on an attribute of an `ActiveRecord::Base` models DB column causes some sort of conflict. When you remove the `attr_accessor` method and instead add whats supposed to be its exact equivalent...

```
def name
  name
end
```

and then try to call that you get an infinitely recursive looping of your call because the `.name` getter method we defined above is calling itself and not accessing the ActiveRecord getter method that actually pulls data from your DB.

Im guessing that somehow active_record model classes will just throw you an `undefined method` error rather than make the recursive call that ends in a `stack level too deep` error.

However since you arent getting a `stack too deep` error my next guess is that the `attr_accessor` you defined overrides the dynamically created `ActiveRecord::Base` getter while rails is still attempting to access the overridden method ( which dosnt exist anymore ). Possibly resulting in the `undefined method 'name'` error.

But...

When you add your own getter method this way... then it works...

```
def name
  super
end
```

this is because with `super` your class is just inheriting the behavior of its dynamically defined `ActiveRecord::Base` getter method. You can test this by adding...

```
def name
  super
  'Foo'
end
```

And when you call `@model.name` you'll see that `Foo` is returned. Remove the 'Foo' from the method and what you have being returned is a `super` call to the dynamically created `ActiveRecord::Base` getter method.

Im open to edits and input on this answer. This is my logical conclusion from testing in my console and doing some reading.

### When to use `attr_accessor`

Also, to answer your question further about when to use `attr_accessor`...

You would use this when you want to create and store information that is business-logic as well as model related, and only lasts for the duration of the request/instance life cycle.

For example raw passwords ( although I cringe at anyone manipulating raw passwords )

or something like...

`@stock.current_price`

where `@stock` is a `ActiveRecord::Base` object but `.current_price` is calculated or retrieved from an API upon instantiation of the `@stock` object because it doesn't make sense to persist and retrieve from the DB an ever changing value such as the price of a stock at any given point in time.

Comment: can you help me to explain when i need to use attr_accessor ?

Comment: this is a really good explanation. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370960/what-is-attr-accessor-in-ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370960/what-is-attr-accessor-in-ruby)

Comment: @thiênlâmtrần You're welcome. Give an upvote to answers and comments that were helpful :)

Comment: @thiênlâmtrần Also please mark this as the answer if it was correct :)

Comment: @thiênlâmtrần I updated my answer as the original answer was wrong. While you still dont need an `attr_accessor` for an `ActiveRecord::Base` model... I got wrong the reason you were getting the error. Ive corrected my answer and this should be more helpful.