# Declaring an instance variable outside of `initialize` method

Tags: ruby, initialization, instance-variables

I have been taught to declare my instance variables with `def initialize`. I have been under the impression that I could declare instance variables only within my `initialize` methods.

Nevertheless, I declared an instance variable `@foo` outside my `initialize` method, and made it work as I intended:

```
class FooBar
    def initialize(bar)
        @bar = bar
    end

    def foo_as_instance_var
        @foo = @bar.split(' ')
        @foo
    end
end

x = "something wicked this way comes"
y = FooBar.new(x)
puts y.foo_as_instance_var
```

Why am I able to declare an instance variable outside of `initialize` method?  Since I can declare instance variables in any method, is there a best practices rule I should follow, regarding where to declare instance variables (i.e., declare them within `initialize`) or does it not matter?

Comment: Doesn't matter. Do what makes sense. You were under the wrong impression if you think it should only happen in initialize. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4370960/3784008) for more info on use of instance variables outside initialize.

Comment: @anothermh I was.  And the question was definitely lingering at the back of my head...

Comment: To be able to access across instance methods, that is the whole point of instance variables.

Comment: @anothermh lol, I literally forgot or missed `attr_accessor`. Thanks!

Comment: It's a nice convention, but just that. You can actually declare instance variables from anywhere using `instance_variable_set` (but I wouldn't advise doing that unless you must for metaprogramming)

Comment: @maxpleaner for _dynamic_ programming actually, which is not mandatory _meta_ :)

Comment: [Mandatory reading](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set) for anyone considering using `instance_variable_set`.

Comment: If you were only allowed to assign to instance variables inside `initialize`, then you could never, ever change them, except by calling `initialize` again. Who told you that? Also, `initialize` is just a method like any other method, so if you weren't allowed to assign to instance variables in methods, then you couldn't assign them in `initialize` either. The fact that you can assign them in `initialize` already proves that you can assign them in methods, because `initialize` is a method. This entire statement makes no sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I have been taught to declare my instance variables with def initialize

Since `initialize` is the first instance method call in an object's life cycle, you typically declare your instance variables right there in order to ensure properly initialized variables. It's also the first place I'd expect instance variables to be defined when reading code.

> I have been under the impression that I could declare instance variables only within my initialize methods.

There's no such restriction. You can declare instance variable anywhere within your instance.

A common use is [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization):

```
class FooBar
  def foo
    @foo ||= expensive_operation
  end
end
```

On the first call, this would evaluate `expensive_operation` and assign the result to `@foo`. On subsequent calls, `@foo` is returned.

Another popular example is Rails which uses instance variables to pass data from the controller to its view:

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @foos = Foo.all
  end
end
```

> is there a best practices rule I should follow, regarding where to declare instance variables

It depends on their purpose (see above examples). As a general rule, declare them in a way that avoids undefined variables (`nil` errors) and structure your code so it is easy to read / follow.

Answer (score 6):

Just to add to Stefan's excellent answer

> I have been taught to declare my instance variables with `def initialize`

A common mistake that ruby newbies make is something like this:

```
class Person
  @name = "John"

  def introduce
    puts "Hi, my name is #{@name}"
  end
end
```

And then they wonder why their names are not printed. To make this work, one can set the variable `@name` in the initializer, just as the instruction says.

Answer (score 3):

Lets start with the biggest misnomer -  in Ruby there is no separate step of declaring variables -  Variables are declared as you set them.

What the difference? Look at Java for example:

```
public class Bicycle {

    private int cadence;
    private int gear;
    private int speed;

    public Bicycle(int startCadence, int startSpeed, int startGear) {
        gear = startGear;
        cadence = startCadence;
        speed = startSpeed;
    }
}
```

We have to declare all the instance variables before we set them in the initializer (Bicycle). The same code in Ruby reads:

```
class Bicycle
  def initialize(cadence, speed, gear)
    @cadence = cadence
    @speed = speed
    @gear = gear
  end
end
```

There is no declaration - only assignment. Ruby will even let you access instance variables which have not been set without error.

```
irb(main):003:0> @not_set
=> nil
```

You can't do that (generally) in languages where variables must be defined*.

> I have been taught to declare my instance variables with def
>   initialize. I have been under the impression that I could declare
>   instance variables only within my initialize methods.

**Nonsense.** You can assign instance variables anywhere. Its commonly done in everything from setters and mutators (methods that alter an object) to factory methods (class methods that return an instance) or anywhere that you are altering the state of an object.

```
class Book 

  def initialize(title, author)
    @title = title
    self.author = author # calls the setter.
  end

  # A factory method
  def create_from_csv(filename)
    # ...
  end

  # A very contrived setter
  def author=(author)
    @author = "#{author.forename.upcase}. #{author.surname}"
  end

  # a mutator
  def out_of_print!
    @out_of_print = true
    @last_printed = Date.today
  end
end
```

However the `initialize` method is where you should handle initializing your objects (duuh) and is thus the obvious place to set initial values.

Comment: * well unless you are talking about Javascript which is a very special snowflake.

Comment: _"access instance variables which have not been set without error"_ – there will be a warning, though (if enabled).