# Can´t pass a test in rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

```
it "should set token of player 1 to X" do
            @game.setplayer1
            @game.player1.should eql "X"
        end
```

My method

```
def setplayer1
        @output.player1.eql? "X"        
    end¨
```

I´am still getting expected:

```
  Failure/Error: @game.player1.should eql "X"

   expected: "X"
        got: nil
```

I don´t know where is the problem and why it´s not passing the test.

Comment: Would you share `player1` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `setplayer1` doesn't actually set `player1` to be any value, so when you access it, its still nil.

A side note, it is more preferred to use `<attribute_name>=` as your setter method instead of `set_<attribute_name>`. Note that you can use `attr_accessor` for to generate simple getters and setters, see [What is attr_accessor in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370960/what-is-attr-accessor-in-ruby) for more details.