# undefined method `my_attr=' for #<My_class:0x000001> (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

i'm creating a new Person class in a Person.rb file.
When i use `ruby Person.rb` in my terminal it shows a NoMethodError:

```
Person.rb:12:in `<main>': undefined method `name=' for #<Person:0x00000001abb6d8> (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  name
```

this is the code i wrote:

```
class Person
    attr :name, :age, :gender
end

person = Person.new

person.name = "John"
person.age = 55
person.gender = "male"

puts(person.name, person.age, person.gender)
```

any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at [the documentation of `Module#attr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-attr), you will see that there are three "overloads" for using it:

> ## `attr(name, …)` → `nil`
>
> ## `attr(name, true)` → `nil`
>
> ## `attr(name, false)` → `nil`

The documentation then further explains the differences between the three:

> The first form is equivalent to `attr_reader`. The second form is equivalent to `attr_accessor(name)` but deprecated. The last form is equivalent to `attr_reader(name)` but deprecated.

So, the first and third forms only generate readers, not writers. The second form generates a reader and a writer, but it only takes a single `name` formal parameter, you cannot use it to generate multiple attributes.

Also, forms two and three are deprecated and all three forms are non-idiomatic.

If you want to fix your code using the non-idiomatic `Module#attr`, you need to do this:

```
attr :name  , true
attr :age   , true
attr :gender, true
```

You can simplify this a little using something like

```
%i[name age gender].each do |attribute|
  attr attribute, true
end
```

However, as mentioned in the documentation, this form is deprecated, and as I mentioned earlier, `Module#attr` is non-idiomatic.

The idiomatic way is to use the `Module#attr_*` family of methods, i.e. [`Module#attr_reader`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-attr_reader), [`Module#attr_writer`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-attr_writer), and [`Module#attr_accessor`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor):

```
attr_accessor :name, :age, :gender
```

Note that since your `Person` class doesn't actually have any behavior, you could simply replace it with a `Struct`:

```
Person = Struct.new(:name, :age, :gender)
```

However, note that accessors in general and writers in particular are not good object-oriented design. Objects should *do* something, they should have *behavior*. Your `Person` objects don't have any behavior, they just contain data. Also, an object should be valid after it is created, but your `Person` objects are empty when they are created. And lastly, if at all possible, objects should be *immutable*.

We can make sure that the object is valid after creation by adding an initializer:

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name, :age, :gender

  def initialize(name, age, gender)
    self.name, self.age, self.gender = name, age, gender
  end
end

person = Person.new('John', 55, 'male')
```

Note: [`Struct`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Struct.html) will create an initializer for us.

If we want to make the object immutable, we need to remove the writers (or make them `private`). Unfortunately, `Struct` won't do that for us:

```
class Person
  attr_reader :name, :age, :gender

  private

  attr_writer :name, :age, :gender

  def initialize(name, age, gender)
    self.name, self.age, self.gender = name, age, gender
  end
end

person = Person.new('John', 55, 'male')
```

Now, `person` is fully initialized after creating it, and it can no longer be changed.

Comment: thank you for the exaustive explanation! P.S: i ack many of the hints you wrote about object oriented design. I'm just playing around with ruby

Answer (score 0):

Some modifications you need to do:

please use `attr_accessor :name, :age, :gender` in your ruby class

and then try:

```
 puts person.name
 puts person.age
 puts person.gender
```

It should work for you..

Comment: it worked! can you also briefly explain the reason why? i'm new to ruby and i posted this question because i think there is no general answer around regarding this. P.S: i added an arrow up to your answer but it doesn't show the +1 because i'm a new user (i suppose)

Comment: `attr_accessor` is a Getter and Setter method in Ruby. what you wrote was wrong syntax. And the `puts` method does not need parenthesis. For more information, please refer  `https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/attr_accessor`

Comment: "what you wrote was wrong syntax" – That is wrong. If it was wrong syntax, it would terminate with a `SyntaxError` before even running.

Comment: @tronux: you're welcome.. this SO post will help you most for this ruby concept: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370960/what-is-attr-accessor-in-ruby