# In Rails i am not able to set `attr_accessor` from concern in model level

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, activesupport-concern

I have a concern looking something like

```
module StrategyConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    attr_accessor :strategy_display_name
  end
end
```

and i have included it in my model `include StrategyConcern`
but when i try to assign value to that like this

```
obj["strategy_display_name"] = "test_display_name"
```

i am getting error

```
undefined method `strategy_display_name=' for #<Test:0x00007f868e4aa350>
```

I want that object attribute to access, without getting the mentioned error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that `obj` is an instance of the model, you should use

```
obj.strategy_display_name = "test_display_name"
```

So just get rid of the square brackets (`[]` which are mainly used when working with arrays and hashes)

You can read more about accessors there for instance: [What is attr_accessor in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370960/what-is-attr-accessor-in-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use variables in models using the following way:

```
obj.strategy_display_name = 'test_display_name'
obj.strategy_display_name
```

The `[]` operator for active record models is used to access variables holding column values from the database, not instance variables