# Access instance variable using its name (as symbol)

Tags: ruby, class, variables

In Ruby, I have this class:

```
class Position
  attr_reader :x, :y
  def initialize(x, y)
      @x, @y = x, y
  end
end
```

What I want to do is to access x and y variables using the symbol, something like this:

```
axis = :x
pos = Position.new(5,6)
 #one way:
pos.axis # 5 (pos.x)
 #other way:
pos.get(axis) # 5 (pos.x)
```

Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074729/get-the-value-of-an-instance-variable-given-its-name) I've found with this code, I can achieve the second behavior.

```
#...
class Position
  def get(var)
    instance_variable_get(("@#{var}").intern)
  end
end
```

But it seems ugly and inefficient (especially converting symbol to string and back to symbol). Is there a better way?

Comment: `x` and `y` are not variables, but methods :-)

Comment: Right, I am still getting used to it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are ways to do both techniques. Assuming we already have your class definition,

```
position = Position.new(1, 2)
axis = :x
position.send axis #=> 1
axis = :y
position.send axis #=> 2
```

The `Object#send` method accepts at least a symbol representing the name of the method to call, and call it. You can also pass arguments to the method after the name and a block, too.

The second way to do this (using your `Position#get` method) is

```
class Position
  def get(axis)
    send axis
  end
end

position = Position.new(1, 2)
axis = :x
position.get axis #=> 1
axis = :y
position.get axis #=> 2
```

I recommend this way because it encapsulates the technique for getting the values. Should you need to change it later, you don't need to change all the code that uses `Position`.

Answer (score 9):

Easy, use the `send` method

```
class Position
  attr_reader :x, :y

  def initialize(x, y)
    @x, @y = x, y
  end
end
 => nil 

pos = Position.new(5,5)
 => #<Position:0x0000010103d660 @x=5, @y=5> 

axis = :x
 => :x 

pos.send axis
 => 5
```

Comment: There is no need to convert `axis` to string. `axis` is a Symbol, and in `.send`, the method name must be passed as a Symbol. => `pos.send(axis)`

Comment: This doesn't actually access the instance variable, it just calls the accessor.