# How can I change this from a local to instance variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables

I have this block of code:

```
if %w[ups fedex usps].include?(carrier.slug)
  send(carrier.slug).track(number)
end
```

Which effectively replicates:

```
ups.track(number)
fedex.track(number)
usps.track(number)
```

But what I now need is that, with instance variables:

```
@ups.track(number)
@fedex.track(number)
@usps.track(number)
```

What's the equivalent?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1074729/get-the-value-of-an-instance-variable-given-its-name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if %w[ups fedex usps].include?(carrier.slug)
  var_name = "@#{carrier.slug}"
  instance_variable_get(var_name).track(number)
end
```

By the way, your interpretation is incorrect.

```
ups.track(number)
fedex.track(number)
usps.track(number)
```

These are treated as methods, not local variables. If there's no method `ups`, your code will fail (even if there is a local var with the same name).